# Sketch $\frac{\sin(x)}{1 + a \cos(x)}$ for "every possible" $a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, curves

I am trying to sketch $$f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{1 + a \cos(x)}$$ for every possible $a \in \mathbb{R}$, but I can not find good ranges of a which the function behaves similarly in that specific range. How can I categorize my $a$ to help me sketch it?

Comment: I would consider $a \in (-1,1)$ for a different case because there aren't any asymptotes in that range.

Comment: I think I figured it out! a < -1, a = 1, -1< a < 1, a = 1, a > 1